# getting 500 Internal Server Error on ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

When calling below code, I'm getting **500 Internal Server Error** whereas same code is running without any issue at my local machine.

```
   $(document).on('click', '#continue-to-payment', function () {
        var selected = $('#addr_selected').val();
        if (selected > 0) {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../da/userDA.php",
                data:"addr_id="+selected+"&funId=9",
                success: function (data) {
                alert(data); //<-- to display, parameter values, which was passed for this request 
                    redirectPost('orderConfirm.php', {success: data});
                }
            });


        } else {
            alert("Please provide shipping address !!");
        }

    });
```

But, when I have changed this line of code

```
data:"addr_id="+selected+"&funId=9",
```

to

```
data:'{"addr_id":"'+selected+'","funId":"9"}',
```

error disappeared, but doesn't passing any value along with this request. Could anyone help me to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Please post the content of your `userDA.php` file, since that's where the 500 error is originating from.

Comment: As of now, It has only `$funId = $_POST['funId'];
echo $funId;
echo $_POST['addr_id'];` So that, it will display what was values sent to `userDA.php`

Comment: @downvoter Any specific reason for downvoate ?

Answer (score 1):

Try passing `data` a JS object, since this will ensure it is correctly serialised during the POST request:

```
data: {
    'addr_id': selected,
    'funId': 9
}
```